# PDO MySQL prepare->execute INSERT INTO not appearing in Database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am writing a program to monitor a bunch of computers I own for security reasons. I am attempting to store a users data in a database with the following code:

```
$con->prepare("INSERT INTO `myComputers` (`hwid`, `ip`, `pcname`, `username`, `os`, `country`, `first`) VALUES (:hwid, :ip, :pcname, :username, :os, :country, :first")->execute(
      array(
        ':hwid'        => $data_array['hwid'],
        ':ip'          => $data_array['ip'],
        ':pcname'      => $data_array['pcname'],
        ':username'    => $data_array['username'],
        ':os'          => $data_array['os'],
        ':country'     => $data_array['country'],
        ':first'       => $data_array['first']
      )
    );
```

I am not getting any errors but when I look in my database there is no data being inserted. I have checked that each item in `$data_array` is actually  set to something. Also here is my MySQL database construction query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myComputers(
    hwid VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ip VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    pcname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    os VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    country CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    first int(11) NOT NULL
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I have been stuck on this for hours with no idea what is causing the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is some test data I am parsing (I've changed my IP address):

```
blahblah
123.12.123.123
PotatoPC
MyPotato
Windows
AU
1447671823
```

Comment: I assume the missing `:` from `first` in the array is a typo?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Although this does not fix the problem.

Comment: You're missing an end `)` in your SQL query. I would expect that prepare to fail and you get a warning about calling `execute` on a non-object. Look at your errors logs and enable exception mode on your PDO connection.

Comment: Thankyou for this, fixed my stupid mistake. A new set of eyes helps a lot.
Although it is strange as I did have exception mode enabled on PDO connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing quotes and bracket issue at `:first")` it is `:first)")`

So the whole statement would be

```
$con->prepare("INSERT INTO `myComputers` (`hwid`, `ip`, `pcname`, `username`, `os`, `country`, `first`) VALUES (:hwid, :ip, :pcname, :username, :os, :country, :first)")->execute(
 array(
        ':hwid'        => $data_array['hwid'],
        ':ip'          => $data_array['ip'],
        ':pcname'      => $data_array['pcname'],
        ':username'    => $data_array['username'],
        ':os'          => $data_array['os'],
        ':country'     => $data_array['country'],
        ':first'       => $data_array['first']
      )
    );
```